# Is there an \autoref for "proof"?

Tags: hyperref, amsthm

I am using the `proof` environment and would like to use `\autoref` to hyperlink to the proof from the proposition, because the proof is in a later section. I cannot seem to find the right prefix for a proof; instead, using `\begin{proof}[theproof]\label{proof:theproof}` with `See \autoref{proof:theproof} for proof` after the proposition does not produce anything.

Here is my obligatory MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}\label{proof:theproof}
Hello. This is a proof.
\end{proof}
According to \autoref{proof:theproof}\ldots
\end{document}
```

I have even tried, to no avail, including `\newcommand{\proofautorefname}{Proof}` in the preamble, but this changes nothing for me.

I see I may not be the only one with this problem also; unfortunately, [this poor guy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176970/have-theorems-hyperlink-to-proofs-and-visa-versa) seems to have given up completely despite a response.

Comment: `proof` is an unnumbered environment. There is no counter `proof` so there is nothing which can be referred.

Comment: You couls use `\hypertarget`, `\hyperlink` instead; something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}\hypertarget{proof:theproof}{\mbox{}}Hello. This is a proof.
\end{proof}
According to \hyperlink{proof:theproof}{the proof}...\ldots
\end{document}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `proof` is an unnumbered environment, there is no associated counter so there is no string to be picked by `\autoref` and forcing numbering for proofs seems odd.

I'd suggest you to use the `\hyperlink`, `\hypertarget` mechanism provided by `hyperref` instead; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref} 

\begin{document} 

We'll see in \hyperlink{proof:theproof}{the proof}...

\newpage% just for the example so the proof is in a different page

\begin{proof}[\hypertarget{proof:theproof}{\proofname}]
Hello. This is the proof. 
\end{proof} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps "forcing numbering for proofs seems odd," but there should be a system for accurately linking propositions to proofs when the proof is too long to be stuck in just below the claim. This discussion actually has me thinking of broader question of the best way to organize propositions and formal proofs when the proofs are too long for the manuscript, which means publishers will want them in a separate document anyway.

Comment: @JWells the standard way is to use something like `\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:foo}]...\end{proof}` and then use my answer if hyperlinked is required.

Answer (score 5):

The standard `amsthm` `proof` environment does not use a counter, as such `hyperref` can't provide a `\proofautorefname` command.

This uses the `thmtools` package which provides the correct `\autoref` and `hyperref` facilities. However, it's necessary to override the `proof` environment by `amsthm` in order to provide a counter value (`proof`).

The ending `qed` box is some eye-candy-addition by me. The spacings has to be changed at will.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\let\proof\relax%

\usepackage{xpatch}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\declaretheorem{proof}
\xpretocmd{\endproof}{\raggedright\qed}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}\label{proof:theproof}
Hello. This is a proof. \blindtext
\end{proof}
According to \autoref{proof:theproof}\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of the `\xpretocmd` line, you can simply use `\declaretheorem[qed=\qedsymbol]{proof}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks, I had no idea about that option

Comment: Interesting take on the issue. My only suggestion would be to use the `remark` theorem style with a proof to distinguish it from the `plain` style, which is intended for propositions/theorems.

Comment: @JWells: How should I know about the `plain` style and what is intended? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- you can look at the documentation for `amsthm` (`texdoc amsthm`).  this is undergoing revision (and expansion) at the moment; the update will be posted first at http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex, so look there in a week or two.